# Is it possible to launch .Net applications under the Visual Studio debugger using Image File Execution Options

Tags: c#, windows, debugging

I am attempting to debug a C#/.Net application that is started by a script. I've used Image File Execution Options in the past to debug native applications.

When I follow the instructions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed(VS.71).aspx), my application halts and the Visaul Studio debugger launches but I am unable to open managed symbol files or set breakpoints on managed source code.

The MSDN page notes:

> If the application is managed, Visual Studio launches with the Debugger Type set to Auto. Before you debug, change the Debugger Type from Auto to Mixed in the Property Pages dialog box. For more information, see Specifying Debugger Settings.

Which implies managed debugging is possible with IFEO but [this blog entry](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmstall/2006/02/16/ifeo-and-managed-debugging/), says this is not possible.

Comment: Hmm, no, that still works fine.   Just be sure to set the Debugger key to vsjitdebugger.exe and to tick the "Manually choose the debug engines" when the dialog pops up.  You next get a dialog to pick the engine, pick Managed and Native.  Which debug engine is active first depends on where the break occurs.  Usually native.

Comment: Thanks. Manually choosing the debug engine is what I was missing.

I also had to manually open a C# source file and set a breakpoint that showed in the VS as if it wouldn't be hit. But as soon as the .Net dll was loaded, the symbols loaded and the breakpoint became valid.

If you can state your comment in the form of an answer I'll mark it as correct.